# How to embed links from websites which use the og tag? PHP

Tags: php

I have a Social Networking website and I wanted to know how i could get the content from a websites OG tag. Like how Facebook embeds links into their website. I Only want to get the title,img,desc and nothing else then embed that link into my website. I used regex to validate if its a link and if it was post it in a link, Nevertheless i dont know how to embed the links :) I would really like if someone Could help. Also the code which i have does this :
Just saves the post to the database 
Shows the posts from the database (After detecting if its a link,video,image,gif...)

This is my first post on stackoverflow, I really do apologize if i didnt give good info. If you would like some info

Comment: Hey Ryan :) show us some code ;) and what is an op tag? can u give an example?

Comment: @Paket2001 Sorry i made a typo ! Its op which stands for OpenGraph and is used for rich results. like so: <meta name="og:title" content="The Rock"/> if you add this to your website and send the website link on facebook its going to add a rich reslt other than that blue line. I want to get the values of the og tag and embed them in my own website !